# How to insert commas amongst any letter and following any digit using regex

Tags: python, regex

```
fileinput = open('INFILE.txt', 'r')
fileoutput = fileinput.read()
replace = re.sub(r'([A-Za-z]),([A-Za-z])', r'\1\2', fileoutput)
print replace
replaceout = open('OUTFILE.txt', 'w')
replaceout.write(replace)
```

The code above delete commas among any letter whether CapsLocks or not. How to insert commas among any letter and digit? I try the code

```
replace = re.sub(r"([a-z])([0-9])", r",\1", fileoutput)
```

but it does not work. Any suggestion how to insert commas among any letter and any digit?

Comment: Please show sample input from your file and where/how you want to insert commas.

Comment: Vilniausnuoma483,NuomaVilniuiiraplinkVilniu. I want insert comma before digit 483.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you understand how to add in the comma and reference out what you want. The brackets around the pattern allow you to capture a value in the regex pattern to return later. First one you capture is referenced as \1 and second \2 and so on.

Inside the square brackets you are telling the regex what you want it to match and without further instructions in the regex pattern it's referencing a single character it's trying to match. So the code below will put a comma in between each character.

```
import re

test = "123frogger"

replace = re.sub(r'([A-Za-z0-9])', r'\1,', test)
```

creating the output

```
1,2,3,f,r,o,g,g,e,r,
```

Here's an update based on one of your comments above about the content of what you are trying to adjust.

```
import re

test = "Vilniausnuoma483,NuomaVilniuiiraplinkVilniu"

replace = re.sub(r'([A-Za-z])([0-9].*)', r'\1,\2', test)
```

It will output the following.

```
Vilniausnuoma,483,NuomaVilniuiiraplinkVilniu
```

Comment: If I use your regex in code I get NameError: name 're' is not defined

Comment: do you have the re library imported?

Comment: Regex code does create output. Library re is importer.

Comment: If you are getting NameError for re not defined. It means you are missing the line "import re" before the use of re.subs.

Comment: No. import re is there.

Comment: Sorry the only time I can think NameError shows up is when a variable isn't declared such as re being a variable pointing to a function from the import statement. Try closing down your python environment and restart the kernel in case there is something weird going on with that. Basically a NameError is saying I'm calling this variable but it's not be declared so I don't know what it's supposed to be calling. Typically any time you call on a variable you need it to be after you have declared it. Such as "import re" or "re = somethingorother"

Comment: I think error is in regex description. I happens while copying.

Comment: There's no error in the regex pattern that I can see, it works just fine in my environment. And a NameError is referencing that a variable name is not assigned appropriately to what is being called (that being 're'). Only way I replicate the error you have is when I remove the line 'import re'. Beyond that I'm not sure why you don't seem to be able to call on re after importing the module.